# What exactly is a content level merge?

Tags: git, svn, merge

What is exactly is a content level merge?

I've heard this term used a couple times in git discussions.

Answer (score 8):

A merge between two branches where a *different* set of files has been changed in each branch is a simple (or "trivial") merge. Git doesn't need to look inside the files to see what to do - it just takes the latest of each.

However, if both merge parents change the *same* file, then Git must look inside the file to see how to apply both changes. This is a "content level merge". The results may be applied automatically if there is no conflict, or may require manual resolution.